# What is that generic feeling when you are not excited about a thing and other are utterly thrilled?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What would you call your feeling when everyone from a place you just arrived which is your homeland right from your neighborhood to TV channels is excited for newly launched car models like Audi A8, a toyota cruiser, range rover sports etc and you see advertisement everywhere while you are ok with it since it has become so common to you that you don't feel like discussing even sometimes feeling like giving them a lesson or two about the glitches and design flaws in these cars and you aren't into automobile business in anyway (neither designer nor sales men). You are a commoner. Just that your current country of residence is well a developed country while your home country isn't.

PS: car examples are hypothetical. Its a generic feeling for anything you knew before everyone else and you are like i am about to steal their thunder, shall i or shall i not coz i will appear bragger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the term *blasé*. It doesn't require that others are enthusiastic, but it does describe an indifference or lack of enthusiasm that may seem incongruent with the subject matter.

> **blasé** *adjective*
>   Unimpressed with or indifferent to something because one has experienced or seen it so often before.
>   ‘He seems so blasé, that it makes me wonder whether these sorts of deals occur all the time.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blase)

Answer (score 2):

I like **underwhelmed** here. Similar to *blasé* this doesn't imply that others are impressed, but I think does convey that people would have been expecting a more positive response.

> **Underwhelm** *verb*.
>
> [Fail to impress or make a positive impact on (someone); disappoint.
>   ‘American voters seem underwhelmed by the choices for president’](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/underwhelm)